# PowerPoint Slide count

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How do I get the total slide count across multiple PowerPoint presentations? I have a folder with ~20 PowerPoint files and I'm curious to know the combined slide count.

I know you can right click and check the file info to get that files info, but it just says "(multiple values)" if I select multiple files (which is silly because selecting multiple media files will give you their total length).

I did a google but couldn't find any relevant info. Is there an easy way to do this? Or some sort of known script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael Halpin has a Powershell script that does this. The original site is gone, but it is archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20180204011318/http://michaelhalpin.azurewebsites.net:80/use-powershell-to-get-numbers-of-slides-in-powerpoints/

Here is the script:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
[Alias()]
[OutputType([psobject])]
Param(
# The folder containing the files to count
[Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,
        Position=0)]
$Path = 'C:\temp'
)
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName Office
Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint

Write-Verbose "Getting files from $path"
$files  = Get-ChildItem -filter *.ppt* -Path $Path

[psobject]$NumberOfSlides= @()

Foreach ($file in $files){
    $application = New-Object -ComObject powerpoint.application
    Write-Verbose "Opening $file" 
    $presentation = $application.Presentations.open($file.fullname)

    $slideCount =  New-Object System.Object
    $slideCount | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Name -value $file.name
    $slideCount | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Slides -value $presentation.Slides.Count

    #Introduce a slight wait so powerpnt.exe has time to process file
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
    $presentation.Close()

    $NumberOfSlides += $slideCount
    }

$NumberOfSlides

Write-Verbose "Cleaning up processes"
get-process powerpnt | Stop-Process
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. It's a little slow and dirty because it opens up every pp file to get the slide count, but it gets the job done.